# Strange java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, hibernate, jvm, javassist

I use Hibernate run time class instrumentation.
Strange error happens however:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack in method pkg.model.ValueList$1.<init>(Lpkg/model/ValueList;)V at offset 2
    at pkg.model.ValueList.<init>(ValueList.java:24)
```

I've created my own ClassLoader that applies transformations and
use it to boostrap the whole application.
Here is the method that applies transformations:

```
    private byte[] transform(byte[] original) {
        for (ClassFileTransformer transformer : transformers) {
            try {
                byte[] transformed = transformer.transform(this,
                        className, null, null, original);
                if (transformed != null) {
                    original = transformed;
                    classReader = new ClassReader(transformed);
                    try {
                        CheckClassAdapter.verify(classReader, true,
                            new PrintWriter(System.out));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalClassFormatException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return original;
    }
```

I run application with this class loader and get the following output:

```
<init>(Lpkg/model/ValueList;)V
00000 ValueList$1 ValueList  :  :     ALOAD 0
00001 ValueList$1 ValueList  : ValueList$1  :     ALOAD 1
00002 ValueList$1 ValueList  : ValueList$1 ValueList  :     INVOKEVIRTUAL pkg/model/ValueList$1.$javassist_write_this$0 (Lpkg/model/ValueList;)V
00003 ValueList$1 ValueList  :  :     ALOAD 0
00004 ValueList$1 ValueList  : ValueList$1  :     INVOKESPECIAL java/util/AbstractList.<init> ()V
00005 ValueList$1 ValueList  :  :     RETURN
```

I see nothing wrong at the offset 2.
We call method with proper this (ValueList$1) and a proper argument (ValueList).
And ASM sees nothing bad too, as its verifier throws no exceptions.
Why then JVM verifier rejects this bytecode?

The Hibernate version is 4.1.10.Final.
Here is the part of code that is related to the error:

```
public class ValueList {
    //...
    @Transient
    private List<Value> safeValues = new AbstractList<Value>() {
        // ...
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the error message is misleading. 
Your call to `super()` is not the first statement in the constructor body. If you translate your byte code back to Java it will look something like this:

```
class ValueListInner extends AbstractList<Value> {
    public ValueListInner(ValueList list) {
        javassist_write_this_outer(list);
        super();    
    }

    private void javassist_write_this_outer(ValueList list) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This is not a valid Java code. 
It should probably look like this:

```
<init>(Lpkg/model/ValueList;)V
00000 ValueList$1 ValueList  :  :     ALOAD 0
00001 ValueList$1 ValueList  : ValueList$1  :     INVOKESPECIAL java/util/AbstractList.<init> ()V
00002 ValueList$1 ValueList  :  :     ALOAD 0
00003 ValueList$1 ValueList  : ValueList$1  :     ALOAD 1
00004 ValueList$1 ValueList  : ValueList$1 ValueList  :     INVOKEVIRTUAL pkg/model/ValueList$1.$javassist_write_this$0 (Lpkg/model/ValueList;)V
00005 ValueList$1 ValueList  :  :     RETURN
```

Comment: The message is correct. Before the constructor chained reached the `java/lang/Object` type, the variable array value at index `0` contains a value of the JVM type `undefined`. This type does not know of the method `$javassist_write_this$0` (you can however set fields on this type). Only after the constructor chain is called, you can invoke methods on this type as it was replaced by its actual type.

Comment: Oh, I see, I've just found that in VM Spec: "However, instance fields of this that are declared in the current class may be assigned before calling any instance initialization method.". So, compiler generates PUTFIELD to initialize synthetic fields before calling super constructor. I think I should post an issue to the javassist team.

Comment: @raphw, yes, there is logic, if you know such little details. But agree, the message is very confusing when you are trying to realize what's wrong.

Comment: Is this a javassist generated method where you did not generate byte code yourself? The javassist guys should know about such byte code specifics so I agree that you should absolutely report such an error.